# Request timeout for icmp_seq on MacOS

Tags: ping, macos-sierra, icmp

It all started when I was trying to connect to a VM setup on GCP for SFTP only. Everytime I try to check SSH or setup an SFTP on this machine, it becomes unreachable (and its reachable and well connected on my friend's laptop at the same time).

```
Ping <ip address>
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

I can ping other VMs and also able to SSH into them.

I thought the problem might be with my router. So I used my phone HOTSPOT to connect to internet and tried again. It still did not work. Moreover to my surprise I got same timeouts when I ping www.google.com (strange, because I am able to use internet through chrome browser).

Other details:

- MacBook Pro, High Sierra
- Airtel Broadband/ Vodafone (HOTSPOT)
- Firewall is off.

Others seem to have faced a similar issue (but I could not find any satisfactory answer in these links):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/608194/have-internet-connection-but-cant-ping-external-sites

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you turned `Stealth mode` in `Settings > Security & Privacy > Firewall`.
If it's turned off try turning the whole firewall off, just to test whether that's the culprit.

Comment: Although the same situation has not repeated itself but when I was facing the issue the firewall settings should not have been the concern. Since the ssh was working before that and even now with the same settings. But anyway thanks for suggesting a potential problem area. Strangely I have not faced the same situation again yet.

Comment: Solved my issue. Perfect Thanks!